# Vectorizing Removing Outliers with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Every column (c) within the dataframe contains a time-series of values that contain some extreme outliers, of which the goal is to remove these and substitute them for the value previously seen.

The code below works fine for the purpose but it is extremely slow since I need to run this operation for 7 distinct columns and 59 dataframes in total. Is there anyway to vectorize this operation or make it faster in another way?

Substituting outliers with anything but the value previously seen is not really an option as this would interfere with the time-series nature of the data.

```
for c in df.columns:
    if c == "date":
        continue
    for i in range(len(dfn)):
        if dfn[c].iloc[i] > 5*np.mean(dfn[c]):
            dfn[c].iloc[i] = dfn[c].iloc[i-1]
    end_df = end_df.append(dfn)
```

Example input of outlier removal substitution:

```
[10, 28, 39, 48193, 14]
```

Example output of outlier removal substitution:

```
[10, 28, 39, 39, 14]
```

Comment: is it intentional to recompute the mean of the column at each iteration? (note that once you fix one outlier, the mean would change

Comment: @FLab Very good point. Did not even think of this, it should definitely only be calculated once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter your dataframe by the condition you desire (in this case to be 5 times greater than the mean) and replace with `nan`. Then you can use the build-in `pandas` function `fillna` to substitute with the previous seen value.

Your code will then be

```
import numpy as np

for c in df.columns:
    if c == "date":
        continue
    df.loc[df[c] > 5 * df[c].mean(), c] = np.nan
    df[c].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Perfect, this solution decreased execution time by a significant margin. Thanks!